# ScintillaNet - Can't add it to toolbox

Tags: c#, .net, scintilla

I've read [this tutorial](https://dubreville.wordpress.com/2013/02/23/scintillanet-getting-started-tutorial/)

to add ScintillaNet to my project.

Summary:

- I've added the SciLexer.dll and SciLexer64.dll by clicking on my project name => Add => Existing Element
- I've added a reference of ScintillaNet.dll by clicking on my project name => Add => Reference
- I've clicked on the toolbox => Choosing Elements (or something like that, I use another language)

But when I'm searching for the ScintillaNet.dll in the following dialog by clicking on "Browse" and select this dll there will be an error like "There are no compontents, which can be added to toolbox" (or something like that, I translated it in english).

What is my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

- Add ScintillaNET from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jacobslusser.ScintillaNET/) to your project.
- Build your project.
- Look at your toolbox, it should be a new tab called **ScintillaNET** with two items: Pointer and Scintilla. Drag the last one into a form to see the textbox-like control in action.